# Clear spinner contents on button click

Tags: android

I have a spinner that is dynamically loaded with data as following

```
final  String[] sku = CrownApplication.mDb.getAllSKUs(Qsearch);
                if((sku.length>=1)){ 
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CrownTakeOrder.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sku);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                }
```

This works fine,now I have a button that on clicking gets the value and sets other fields blank e.g Edittext as below. The only problen is I am not able to clear the spinner so once everything else is cleared the spinner still remains with the old Values

```
if (!mError) {
                mSKU = mSpner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Qsearch =mQuery.getText().toString();
                quantity =mQuantity.getText().toString();
                String[] parts = mSKU.split(" - ");
                str1 = parts[0];  
                str2 = parts[1];   

                addBody(Qsearch,mSKU,quantity);

                mQuery.setText("");
                mTxtview.setText("");
                mQuantity.setText("");
                mSKU = "empty";

               //mSpner.setAdapter(null);

            }
```

I have tried to use

```
 mSpner.setAdapter(null);
```

But my app crashes....How to empty spinner? I am coding on

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
mSpner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CrownTakeOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]));
```

Comment: array dimension missing